# To reduce code duplication in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

This is my simple controller which is dependent on EventsViewModel. After fetching required fields, i am comparing the data returned and fill it into two variable and finally returning back UpcomingPassedEventViewModel to the view page.

```
      public ActionResult Event()
      {
        int currentUserId = this.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
        var events = this.db.Events
            .Where(e => e.AuthorId == currentUserId)
            .OrderBy(e => e.StartDateTime)
            .Select(e => new EventsViewModel()
             {
               Title = e.Title,
               StartDateTime = e.StartDateTime,
               Name = e.ApplicationUser.UserName
            });
        var upcomingEvents = events.Where(e => e.StartDateTime > DateTime.Now);
        var passedEvents = events.Where(e => e.StartDateTime <= DateTime.Now);
        return View(new UpcomingPassedEventViewModel()
        {
            UpcomingEvents = upcomingEvents,
            PassedEvents = passedEvents
        });
    }
```

Now, i have a partial view _Events like this:

```
     @model App.Models.UpcomingPassedEventViewModel

    <div class="row">
     @if (Model.UpcomingEvents.Any()) {
      @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.UpcomingEvents) }
    else {
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">No events</div> }
   </div>
```

I can render this partial view on Events view page corresponding to events action method in Event controller like this:

```
     @{ Html.RenderPartial("_Events"); }
```

**If i try to render it anywhere else it will throw System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error on this line ---@if (Model.UpcomingEvents.Any())** 
Problem is:

1>If i want to render same partial view on home controller's index view then i have to write full code in index method also.

2> If i do that, then code duplication problem. suppose i have 10 controller and corresponding views then i will have to write same code over and over again.

How to reduce this code duplication. i am already using view model. how to resolve this. I dont want to use repository pattern here.

Comment: In your other views, use `@Html.Action("Event", yourControllerName)` which will call the `Event()` method and render the partial view it returns

Comment: @StephenMuecke please see the updated ques sir

Comment: Use `@Html.Action()` (or `@{ Html.RenderAction(); }`) - not `@Html.Partial()`

Comment: Event action method is not reurning partial view so should i change it to return partial view only ?? Is this the best approach as i have render 7 partial view on same page  then 7 diff action method returning 7 partial view @StephenMuecke

Comment: Yes it should return a partial view, and you should also mark it `[ChildActionOnly]` the user cannot navigate to it.

Comment: okk got it tthnxx sir @StephenMuecke